# exploding an sql table and inserting a row for each day where none exists

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like so which I generated from modestly reworking [this](https://medium.com/analyst-collective/analyzing-your-stripe-data-part-1-measuring-subscription-mrr-603d3597e289#.m4yjcjn0s) data + SQL to display by day, but I want to add in empty days as well with a running tally on the right hand side.

```
╔════════════╦════════╦═════════╦════════╗
║ day        ║ num1   ║ num2    ║ tally  ║
╠════════════╬════════╬═════════╬════════╣
║ 2016-06-10 ║   9.99 ║         ║   9.99 ║
║ 2016-06-12 ║ 136.00 ║    9.99 ║ 145.99 ║
║ 2016-06-14 ║        ║  145.99 ║ 145.99 ║
║ 2016-06-18 ║   9.99 ║  145.99 ║ 155.98 ║
║ 2016-06-19 ║ 210.00 ║  145.99 ║ 365.98 ║
║ 2016-06-22 ║  50.00 ║    9.99 ║ 279.98 ║
║ 2016-06-28 ║  69.99 ║   59.99 ║ 349.97 ║
╚════════════╩════════╩═════════╩════════╝
```

I'm not sure how to make it so that the table transforms into:

```
╔════════════╦════════╦═════════╦════════╗
║ day        ║ num1   ║ num2    ║ tally  ║
╠════════════╬════════╬═════════╬════════╣
║ 2016-06-10 ║   9.99 ║         ║   9.99 ║
║ 2016-06-11 ║        ║         ║   9.99 ║ <- new row with previous value
║ 2016-06-12 ║ 136.00 ║    9.99 ║ 145.99 ║
║ 2016-06-13 ║        ║         ║ 145.99 ║ <- new row with previous value
║ 2016-06-14 ║        ║  145.99 ║ 145.99 ║
║ 2016-06-15 ║        ║         ║ 145.99 ║ <- new row with previous value
║ 2016-06-16 ║        ║         ║ 145.99 ║ <- new row with previous value
║ 2016-06-17 ║        ║         ║ 145.99 ║ <- new row with previous value
║ 2016-06-18 ║   9.99 ║  145.99 ║ 155.98 ║
║ 2016-06-19 ║ 210.00 ║  145.99 ║ 365.98 ║
║ 2016-06-20 ║        ║         ║ 365.98 ║ <- new row with previous value
║ 2016-06-21 ║        ║         ║ 365.98 ║ <- new row with previous value
║ 2016-06-22 ║  50.00 ║    9.99 ║ 279.98 ║
║ 2016-06-23 ║        ║         ║ 279.98 ║ <- new row with previous value
║ 2016-06-24 ║        ║         ║ 279.98 ║ <- new row with previous value
║ 2016-06-25 ║        ║         ║ 279.98 ║ <- new row with previous value
║ 2016-06-26 ║        ║         ║ 279.98 ║ <- new row with previous value
║ 2016-06-27 ║        ║         ║ 279.98 ║ <- new row with previous value
║ 2016-06-28 ║  69.99 ║   59.99 ║ 349.97 ║
╚════════════╩════════╩═════════╩════════╝
```

Comment: Does the database have a calendar type table which has a record for every date?

Comment: @DanBracuk yeah thats the first table, but it only creates a row for when a record exists. i need a bunch of blank date rows that carry over the tally value even if all other values are blank for that row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try (I assume your table is called `tbl`). I use `generate_series` to generate the missing rows, and use a couple of window functions to plug in the appropriate `tally` values in the new rows.

```
with all_dates as (
  SELECT day
   FROM generate_series
        ('2016-06-10'::date,
         '2016-06-28'::date,
         '1 day'::interval) day
), partitioned_data as (
  select d.day, t.num1, t.num2, t.tally,
         sum(case when t.tally is not null then 1 else 0 end) over (order by d.day) as partition_id
    from all_dates d
    left join tbl t
      on t.day = d.day
)
select t.day, t.num1, t.num2,
       first_value(t.tally) over (partition by t.partition_id) as tally
  from partitioned_data t
 order by t.day
```

Comment: That worked beautifully thank you. Only problem left is getting the start date and end date for the range, which I want to pull from an `invoices` table, column `start` has the start date, column `end` has the end date`. i want to find the minimum of that `start` column and maximum of the `end` column and use those for the range.

Comment: edit, nvm i got it! though I think it's a bit convoluted

Answer (score 1):

The data:

```
create table the_data(day date, num1 numeric, num2 numeric, tally numeric);
insert into the_data values
('2016-06-10', 9.99, null, 9.99),
('2016-06-12', 136.00, 9.99, 145.99),
('2016-06-14', null, 145.99, 145.99),
('2016-06-18', 9.99, 145.99, 155.98),
('2016-06-19', 210.00, 145.99, 365.98),
('2016-06-22', 50.00, 9.99, 279.98),
('2016-06-28', 69.99, 59.99, 349.97);
```

The query:

```
with the_data as (  
    select d::date as day, num1, num2, tally
    from generate_series('2016-06-10'::date, '2016-06-28', '1d') d
    left join the_data on d = day
    )
select distinct on (a.day) a.day, a.num1, a.num2, b.tally
from the_data a
join the_data b
on a.day >= b.day and b.tally is not null
order by a.day, b.day desc;

    day     |  num1  |  num2  | tally  
------------+--------+--------+--------
 2016-06-10 |   9.99 |        |   9.99
 2016-06-11 |        |        |   9.99
 2016-06-12 | 136.00 |   9.99 | 145.99
 2016-06-13 |        |        | 145.99
 2016-06-14 |        | 145.99 | 145.99
 2016-06-15 |        |        | 145.99
 2016-06-16 |        |        | 145.99
 2016-06-17 |        |        | 145.99
 2016-06-18 |   9.99 | 145.99 | 155.98
 2016-06-19 | 210.00 | 145.99 | 365.98
 2016-06-20 |        |        | 365.98
 2016-06-21 |        |        | 365.98
 2016-06-22 |  50.00 |   9.99 | 279.98
 2016-06-23 |        |        | 279.98
 2016-06-24 |        |        | 279.98
 2016-06-25 |        |        | 279.98
 2016-06-26 |        |        | 279.98
 2016-06-27 |        |        | 279.98
 2016-06-28 |  69.99 |  59.99 | 349.97
(19 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks for the create table query for my example.

Comment: The best way of communication between OPs and answerers is to provide data structures and sample data in text format easy to reproduce results and possible errors. Unfortunately, most OPs are not aware of this.

Comment: Yeah I tried to mess with SQLFiddle and I ended up messing with it for half an hour and couldn't get it working.

Comment: Sometimes sqlfiddle is annoying indeed. [Click here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/10644/1)